# no matching function for call to ‘tf::TransformListener::lookupTransform(const char [13], const char [5], ros::Time, tf::Transform&)’

Tags: c++, transforms, ros-kinetic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Code**

```
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ar_track_alvar_msgs/AlvarMarkers.h>
#include <ar_track_alvar_msgs/AlvarMarker.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <tf/time_cache.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
#include <math.h>


class Dynamic_tf
{
public:
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  ros::NodeHandle globalNode;
  tf::TransformListener listener;
  tf::Transform transform;

  int i = 1;
  std::string mMapFrame;
  std::string mRobotFrame;

  void robot_callback();

  Dynamic_tf()
  {
    globalNode.param("map_frame", mMapFrame, std::string("map"));
    globalNode.param("robot_frame", mRobotFrame, std::string("base_link"));
  };
};

void Dynamic_tf::robot_callback()
{
   if(i==1){
    try{
      listener.waitForTransform("/ar_marker_1", "/map", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(10.0));
      listener.lookupTransform("/ar_marker_1", "/map", ros::Time(0), transform);
    }

    catch (tf::TransformException &ex) {
      ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
      ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
    }

    tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> now (transform,ros::Time::now(),mMapFrame);
    prev = now;
    i++; //read only one
   }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "dynamic_tf");
  
  Dynamic_tf dynamic;
  int desidered_freq = 15.0;

  ros::Rate r(desidered_freq);

  while (ros::ok())
  {
    dynamic.robot_callback();
    ros::spinOnce();
    r.sleep();
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

**Error**

In member function ‘void Dynamic_tf::robot_callback()’:
/home/simoneforno/simon_ws/src/tf_config/src/tf_husky_dynamic.cpp:72:79: error: no matching function for call to ‘tf::TransformListener::lookupTransform(const char [13], const char [5], ros::Time, tf::Transform&)’
listener.lookupTransform("/ar_marker_1", "/map", ros::Time(0), transform);

**Question**

Why do I get this error? I am newby to C++, sorry for the quite easy question.

Thanks for the one helping me out!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283295/no-matching-function-for-call-to-%E2%80%98tf::transformlistener::lookuptransform(const-char-%5B13%5D,-const-char-%5B5%5D,-ros::time,-tf::transform&)%E2%80%99--------listener.lookuptransform(%22/ar_marker_1%22,-%22/map%22,-ros::time(0),-transform)/) by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Solved**

My oversight, the method lookupTranform want a tf::StampedTransform as argument, and not simply a tf::Transform :)

---

Originally posted by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) with karma: 98 on 2018-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0